# How would I use a pack uri resource with media player?

Tags: c#, wpf, resources, uri, media-player

I have some very simple code which just needs to play a sound with a specified volume, as follows :

```
var mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp.Open(uri);
mp.Volume = volume;
mp.Play();
```

The problem arises because this is part of a Prism module. I don't know where the executing assembly is going to be so I can't use a relative Uri or siteoforigin and MediaPlayer doesn't understand the pack Uri syntax.

I have a resource wav file at the root of my assembly called "notify.wav", but I have no way to pass it into MediaPlayer via a Uri and can't see any other way to load it.

How do I play the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the resource is embedded and the MediaPlayer doesn't support pack uri, you'll need to read the resource in as a stream and write it out to file.You should then be able to load the file into the player as necessary.

I would write the file to my applications directory so that once extracted from the assembly, you can just reference the file directly.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

First you should declare a variable that is string for your media folder's path. This variable holds the path. just like:

```
string url = @"C:\Users\Alico\Documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WpfBrushesTest\WpfBrushesTest\Dido - Thank You.mp4";
```

and then

```
mp.Open(new Uri(url,UriKind.Relative));
```

Answer (score 0):

I’m afraid Media player does not support pack URI.

Have you tried `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory` or `Environment.CurrentDirectory`?

Comment: I don't think GetCurrentDirectory would help me because the resource is embedded in the assembly. I want to know how to pass such a resource to media player. It can't be loose in the file system somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Use ContentResolver class to retrieve the songs from the device and catch with Song.XML that include (TextViews for Title, Article, Album, etc). This XML is later embedded into the MainActivity XML(including ListView)  using Adapter class and then you can call onClick(Song.XML) to play the songs (Setting URI ) on MainActivity XML, later you can set Seekber, Next, Previous and Play function.
**If you want, I will give you full codes** but I am trying to play a song from another Activity using a new UI design and class file, still searching.